# ng-repeat with function inside

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have product with an array as below:

```
$scope.products = [
  {proId:"1",
   proName:"test",
   proPrice:["35","57","67"],
   proSize:["3,5","4,7","7,10"],
   proSizePx:[["30","50"],["40","50"],["70","10"]],
   proHSize:["S","M","L"]
  },

  {proId:"2",
   proName:"Second",
   proPrice:["35","45"],
   proSize:["3,5","4,6"],
   proSizePx:[["30","50"],["40","50"]],
   proHSize:["S","M"],
  },

 {proId:"3",
  proName:"test",
  proPrice:"35",
  proSize:"3,5",
  proHSize:"S",
}
];
```

How can I display it like this and know what size is active?

http://s9.postimg.org/50vtm5cpb/my_dream.gif

I have looked for an app like this but could not find one.

Comment: Are you just asking us to do the whole job? I think that you might need this point of the Angular tutorial : http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_06

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not going to style everything as that is not too relevant to javascript / angular (the question's tags), but here is how to achieve this:

Store the selected size's array index and then use that to determine the other items to display.  So if "L" is selected, the index is 2. proPrize[2] represents the price for "L", proSize[2] is the measurement, proSizePx[2] is w/e that is for "L".

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/TheSharpieOne/G9zQ8/ (Click on the size for each product, and the information for that size will be populated)

Everything is done in the template, the controller just contains the products data.

Here is the template that does all the work:

```
    <div>
        <span class="size" data-ng-repeat="size in product.proHSize" data-ng-click="product.selectedSize = $index" data-ng-class="{selected: product.selectedSize == $index}">{{size}}</span>
    </div>
    <div>proPrice: {{product.proPrice[product.selectedSize]}}</div>
    <div>proSize: {{product.proSize[product.selectedSize]}}</div>
    <div>proSizePx: {{product.proSizePx[product.selectedSize]}}</div>
    <div>proHSize: {{product.proHSize[product.selectedSize]}}</div>
```